# Textview data is false android

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

i'm making a kind of a form app for my end work for school,
but as you can see in the picture, it ain't going verry well.
I'm trying to save all the date from the textviews into a toast message so i can later on put it into a text file.
But now the Toast file says that all my data is "false"
please help me..

http://prntscr.com/7b4how

```
package com.jan.energyservice;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Nieuw_huis1 extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText tekst;
    String s = "jantest";//AlgemeneGegevens.getFilename();
    String uitvoer;
    private String data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nieuw_huis1);

        setupVolgendePagina();

    }

    private void SlaOp(String String, String String2, String String3, String String4, String String5,
            String String6, String String7, String String8, int rdbgrouphuisstatus, String String10,
            String String11, String String12, String String13, String String14, String String15, 
            String String16, String String17, String Titel) {
        try{

        uitvoer += Titel + "\n";
        save(String,String10);
        save(String2,String11);
        save(String3,String12);
        save(String4,String13);
        save(String6,String15);
        save(String7,String16);
        save(String8,String17);
        save(rdbgrouphuisstatus);
        toonresultaat();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }

    private void toonresultaat() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, uitvoer,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

    private void save(int rdbgrouphuisstatus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void save(String invoerTekst, String label) {
          try {
              uitvoer += label + "\n" + invoerTekst;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }

    }


    private void setupVolgendePagina() {
        Button Movebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVolgendePagina1);


        // 2 click listener to run code
        Movebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =(new Intent(Nieuw_huis1.this,Nieuw_huis2.class));
                SlaOp(getText(R.id.txtProjectNaam).toString(),getText(R.id.txtKenmerk).toString(),getText(R.id.txtAdres).toString(),
                        getText(R.id.txtGemeente).toString(),getText(R.id.txtKlantNaam).toString(),getText(R.id.txtDatumBezoek).toString(),
                        getText(R.id.txtNaamAdviseur).toString(),getText(R.id.txtHuisnummer).toString(),R.id.rdbgroupHuisStatus,
                        getText(R.id.tvProjectnaam).toString(),getText(R.id.tvKenmerk).toString(),getText(R.id.tvAdres).toString(),
                        getText(R.id.tvGemeente).toString(),getText(R.id.tvKlantnaam).toString(),getText(R.id.tvDatumBezoek).toString(),
                        getText(R.id.tvNaamAdviseur).toString(),getText(R.id.tvHuisnummer).toString(),getText(R.id.tvAdresgegevens).toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
    public void save(View view){
          //data = tekst;
          try {
             FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(s,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             new PrintStream(fOut).println("Naam van eerste ding");
             fOut.write(data.getBytes());
             fOut.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nieuw_huis1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is my xml file

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAdresgegevens"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/adresgegevens"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProjectnaam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/projectnaam"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtProjectNaam"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKenmerk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/kenmerk"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtKenmerk"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAdres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/adres"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAdres"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGemeente"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gemeente"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtGemeente"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date|text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKlantnaam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/klantnaam"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtKlantNaam"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDatumBezoek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/datumbezoek"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDatumBezoek"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNaamAdviseur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/naamadviseur"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNaamAdviseur"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHuisnummer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Huisnummer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtHuisnummer"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rdbgroupHuisStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdbVerhuur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Verhuur" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdbVerkoop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Verkoop" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdbImmo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Immo" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVolgendePagina1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/VolgendePagina" />

</TableLayout>
```

this is what i edited after your responses.. but still not working

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =(new Intent(Nieuw_huis1.this,Nieuw_huis2.class));
                EditText txtProjectnaam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProjectNaam);
                EditText txtKenmerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtKenmerk);
                EditText txtAdres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAdres);
                EditText txtNaamAdviseur = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNaamAdviseur);
                EditText txtHuisnummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHuisnummer);
                EditText txtGemeente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGemeente);
                EditText txtKlantnaam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtKlantNaam);
                EditText txtDatumBezoek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDatumBezoek);
                TextView tvProjectnaam = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.projectnaam);
                TextView tvKenmerk = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.kenmerk);
                TextView tvAdres = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.projectnaam);
                TextView tvGemeente = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.gemeente);
                TextView tvKlantnaam = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.klantnaam);
                TextView tvDatumBezoek = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.datumbezoek);
                TextView tvNaamAdviseur = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.naamadviseur);
                TextView tvHuisnummer = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.Huisnummer);
                TextView tvAdresGegevens = (TextView) findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.adresgegevens);



                SlaOp(txtProjectnaam.getText().toString(),txtKenmerk.getText().toString(),txtAdres.getText().toString(),
                        txtGemeente.getText().toString(),txtKlantnaam.getText().toString(),txtDatumBezoek.getText().toString(),
                        txtNaamAdviseur.getText().toString(),txtHuisnummer.getText().toString(),R.id.rdbgroupHuisStatus,
                        tvProjectnaam.getText().toString(),tvKenmerk.getText().toString(),tvAdres.getText().toString(),
                        tvGemeente.getText().toString(),tvKlantnaam.getText().toString(), tvDatumBezoek.getText().toString(),
                        tvNaamAdviseur.getText().toString(),tvHuisnummer.getText().toString(),
                        tvAdresGegevens.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

> 05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1$1.onClick(Nieuw_huis1.java:115)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   05-30 19:26:34.383: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-30 19:26:37.943: E/Trace(3262): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

It says something about line 115 which is in SlaOp from the moment i start with the textviews

Comment: SlaOp(String String, arg....) its wrong

Comment: getText(int resId).toString its wrong and u need to first reference it as a text view and then collect text from that.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your view before you use it.

Do this with all view you wanna to use/modify:

`EditText txtKenmerk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtKenmerk)`

Then:

`txtKenmerk.getText().toString();`

Comment: Test your code step by step. For example, put ONLY a toast in your OnClickListener. If it works, Try manually modify one of you EditText. Then add your SlaOp in it.

Answer (score 0):

I check your latest code and you have a problem with your onClick method starting from your TextView's allocations. 
It's an error to cast `findViewById(com.jan.energyservice.R.string.projectnaam)`
to a TextView since it's not a TextView.

What you should really do is `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectnaam)`. that what you configured in your activity xml code. (use R.id for all your objects)

R.string is a special location (string.sml) were you can save all your strings.

The null exception that you got is because you tried to get a view that doesn't exist and therefore you textview was null. afterwards you tried to read from a null function and the exception popped.